# Issue with Android alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am trying to put an alert dialog in my Android app. It's working fine but the problem is after the dialog shows and I click on the main button it show TWO dialog one only title and the other one is title with message content and 2 buttons. I have tried so many tutorials but all same problem I can't figure out.
This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyFull.this);

alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.sms);    

alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.buy, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on buy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: you press cancel and the dilog comes out again?

Comment: yes it comes out again with only the alertdialog title with no message content and no buttons

Comment: Use dialog.dismiss() instead of dialog.cancel()

Comment: nothing happened still same when I click both buttons show up again with title only :(

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to remove `dialog.cancel()`

2) Instead of `alertDialog.show()` have :

```
AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: nothing happened still same when I click both buttons show up again with title only :(

Comment: okay. Is it a possibility that by any chance you are calling the dialog twice? In your code sniplet you haven't mentioned how and where it is being called. You might want to check that.

Comment: I even tried to delete the files and create it again still same and the title that opens is my package name..how does that can happen ?

Comment: How would deleting the filed help? It might be the case the the dialog is being created twice. When ou are click any of the two buttons, the dialog in front disappears but the second dialog at back still is present. That's what I was saying above. Check if dialog is not being created twice. Whereever you are puuting your above code for creating the dialog, is that section of code caled twice by any chance?

Comment: nope its not called twice...now when I click on the main button it show TWO dialog one only title and the other one is title with message content and 2 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyFull.this);

alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.sms);    

alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.buy, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on buy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

alertDialog.show();
```